# How do I get document.body without any child or nested children sections with an id matching a substring?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the entire document.body, except for the children and nested children that have an id that start with a string.

I tried using `document.querySelector('body *:not([id*="mystr"])')` but it only filters out top level children. I want to filter out any level children with matching id string.

Edit: See https://jsfiddle.net/pm7dbac9/

Comment: Can you please share a sample HTML markup where the output is not as you expected.

Comment: Your code seems to working fine because if you do `document.querySelector('body *:not([id*="no"])').classList.add('test')` it only adds the class to the parent `<div>` tag but not to the `<div id="nomatch">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to do it like this

```js
var excludedElements = ["SCRIPT", "META", "TITLE", "STYLE"],
  elements = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("body *"),(function(element) {
    return excludedElements.indexOf(element.nodeName) === -1 && element.id !== "nomatch";
}));

// testing
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.id);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="nomatch">
    pls dont match me
  </div>
  <div id="xyz">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="nomatch">
    pls dont match me
  </div>
  <div id="abc">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is you can't assign more than one unique id, you should do that with classes, I have just showed you an example